# With Android camera API, is it possible to get consistent lighting and exposure across images

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera, emgucv

Simply put...Phone is in a static location meaning it is leaned up against the wall on a night stand.

I ultimately want to take two pictures:

Picture A - Background
Picture B - Someone walks into frame and stands there

Problem: When someone walks into frame, the lighting/white balance/ISO takes over and the background dims.

I've tried:

setAutoExposureLock
setWhiteBalanceLock

They "kind of" work for the REAR facing camera.

Front facing?  Not at all.

What am I trying to accomplish?

I'm trying to do background subtraction in EMGUCV using AbsDiff where Picture A is the Background and Picture B is the overlay.

Thanks...I'd add code, but this is more of a "Can you do this" type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "NO".

As you could see yourself, some cameras (e.g. your rear-facing camera) support some locks, other cameras simply don't. Worse, they not necessarily tell the truth and may pretend that they do.

White balance lock is, in my experience, more reliable than exposure. Luckily, exposure may be easier to compensate with post-processing.

If you don't need high resolution, you can find that preview frames will be easier to compare than captured pictures.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  As it sounds like you're speaking from experience here I will accept this.

Can you elaborate on the preview frames?  Are you talking about taking snapshots from the SurfaceView that is being used to display that camera preview?

Comment: No, I mean using **setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()**